# Does Newton's law and Quantum mechanics also apply for the matter which is not dead?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

The following quote is extracted from the book "The Field-The quest for the secret force":

> ...There was other, quite practical, unfinished business with quantum theory. Bohr and his colleagues only got so far in their experiments and understanding. The experiments they’d conducted demonstrating these quantum effects had occurred in the laboratory, with non-living subatomic particles.*From there, scientists in their wake naturally assumed that this strange quantum world only existed in the world of dead matter. Anything alive still operated according to the laws of Newton and Descartes, a view that has informed all of modern medicine and biology.* Even biochemistry depends upon Newtonian force and collision to work.

Are the above statements correct?

I always get stuck here, according to Newton's laws of motion, everybody continues in the state of motion or rest (w.r.t to an inertial frame), unless and until a force is applied  on it. But, a rat, a dog, a girl!, always pass before me and fluctuate to rest and motion, rest and motion. Are they acted upon by any force to set them in motion or to get them into rest?

If muscles help them move (Pratyay gosh has noticed this significant point), which force make the muscles move. According to Newton's law, they must be acted upon by a force, right?

So, does Newton's laws of motion also apply for the matter which is not dead?

Is Quantum mechanics applicable only for dead matter?

Comment: Are you asking if people moving obeys Newton's Laws?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: No. Newton's Laws are not correct in general but only on day-to-day scales when objects in consideration (animals, vehicles etc.) are reasonably large unlike particles like electrons, protons etc. AND speeds of these objects are much lesser compared to the speed of light in vacuum. Also, Newton's Laws don't say anything about momentum being carried by "non-massive objects", but we know this to be true because electro-magnetic radiation do carry momentum.

Comment: May I suggest you change your title to "Are there situations where quantum mechanics is necessary to describe living organisms?", or something similar?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - I don't think that that is what he's asking. His question is perhaps even more basic than Newtonian mechanics: He appears to be asking whether physics applies to matter that is not dead. The answer is of course yes.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: Thank you for the comment. You are free to make changes. I believe your experience in physics.

Comment: @Godparticle Well, it mostly depends on what you're asking - and that is not very clear from the question.

Comment: Are you asking whether living beings are somehow exempt from Newtonian physics? The quote you give is only meant to imply that, as far as Bohr knew, QM was not necessary to describe living beings. On the other hand, the rest of your question is a lot more muddled.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: I have edited the question.

Comment: The edit doesn't help. This question should be closed because the answer is a trivial "yes".

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the book you're citing was written by a quack with no understanding of physics whatsoever. More to the point, just about every single sentence in the passage you cited is filled with gibberish.

Answer (score 5):

Quantum mechanics applies to EVERYTHING.

Macroscopic objects will have many degrees of freedom, and smoothed out energy levels, and will, to a very good approximation, obey the rules of classical mechanics.

Note however, that there are very many quantum mechanical processes going on inside of our bodies.  Chemistry, for example, is pretty inherently quantum mechanical, and most of the undelying processes of the body involve chemistry pretty heavily.

Comment: The question doesn't have anything to do with quantum mechanics.

Comment: @BenCrowell: the quotation in the OP distinguishes a classical acting "world of living things" and a quantum mechanical "world of dead particles".  This is just wrong.

Comment: The quote has to do with quantum mechanics, but the question is simply a question about Newton's laws.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4):

When I start from rest and begin walking down the street, the force that accelerates me is the static frictional force from the sidewalk.

> If muscles help them move ..., which force make the muscles move...?

The muscles are attached to bones. When I start from rest and begin walking down the street, my muscles are accelerated and begin moving down the street, as well as oscillating as I stride. The forces that cause these accelerations are normal and adhesive forces from the bones.

A different issue is where the *energy* comes from. The energy is electrical potential energy from the food I ate, which gets transformed by my muscles into kinetic energy and heat.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so it seems you are actually asking two separate (and very different) questions in a single post. What you call "dead matter" is what physicists usually simply call "matter", though some specific systems have the additional property of being alive. Being "dead", on the other hand, is not a property.

As such, the answer to your question

> Is Quantum mechanics not applicable for dead matter?

is that quantum mechanics **is** applicable for "dead matter": it is applicable to matter, plain and simple.

There *is* a question, though, on whether quantum mechanics is also applicable to matter which is also alive. During the 1920s and 30s, when Bohr formulated his Copenhagen Interpretation of quantum mechanics, the available experiments were enough to prove that quantum mechanics was necessary (and superseded newtonian mechanics) to describe atomic-level systems, but the evidence available at the time was not enough to say whether it would continue to hold or would need to be modified when applied to living beings.

Faced with that situation, many scientists took two mostly-compatible outlooks: (i) operationally, life was described using newtonian mechanics and worldviews, as there was no experimental reason to doubt their validity at that level (though you should note that this does not mean there was experimental reason to doubt QM at that level, either), and (ii) fundamentally, life would still "in principle" be governed by quantum mechanics, whatever that actually meant.

This is still pretty much the case today.

- There is no experimental evidence either way on whether quantum mechanics fails or continues to hold for living systems.
- There is considerable experimental evidence that quantum mechanics, including the 'quantum weirdness' of superposition states, also holds for (non-living) systems which are macroscopic, and even large enough to be visible to the naked eye. Such systems are bigger (but much less complex) than many organisms which are considered as living.
- There is no experimental reason to doubt that quantum mechanics does describe living beings, and a large body of evidence that it does. This does raise contradictions with everyday experience, because we never observe cats that are |alive⟩+|dead⟩, but
- those contradictions are still unresolved. This is the fundamental open problem in the foundations of quantum mechanics, and it is known as the measurement problem.

On the other hand, the statement that "even biochemistry depends upon Newtonian force and collision to work" is dubious at best. This depends on what size of biomolecule you mean, and computational chemistry for large molecules is notoriously hard, but you can be very accurate in your predictions for amino acids using some pretty hard quantum mechanics, and there are no other explanations for many of those properties that emanate purely from newtonian mechanics.

---

The rest of your question seems to stem from a fundamental confusion between "newtonian mechanics" and Newton's three Laws of Motion.

The former means the worldview and outlook of Newton when tackling physical problems, and in particular the assertion that particles and systems have definite positions, coordinates and momenta, and that these positions and momenta completely characterize the states of the system. It is this what the quote refers to as "the laws of Newton and Descartes".

The latter means the specific assertions that systems in isolation travel in straight lines, accelerations are due to forces, and that every force comes with an equal and opposite reaction. These are a distinct subset of the worldview implied by 'newtonian mechanics', but they also hold ([with a number of subtleties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem#General_example)) in quantum mechanics. These have not really been observed to fail, though of course in the systems where the newtonian worldview fails then they need to be examined very closely.

And, finally, regarding your question that

> But, a rat, a dog, a girl!, always pass before me and fluctuate to rest and motion, rest and motion. Are they acted upon by any force to set them in motion or to get them into rest?

the answer is (a) obviously yes, and (b) completely independent of the validity of quantum mechanics. Rats, dogs and girls move by using their muscles to exert forces on the ground and the objects around them. By Newton's third law, there is a corresponding reaction from the ground which propels them forward.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's law applies on anything of which we can precisely know the position and momentum (not the quantum mechanical particles), no matter whether it is dead or alive. In case of a cat or dog a normal force comes from its weight and the muscles. Due to this normal force frictional force is generated, that helps them move.

Comment: No, the force the muscles make is an internal force. The force that accelerates the cat or dog is the frictional force from the ground.

Comment: On a second thought, I agree with Ben.

Comment: What makes those muscles to move? Which force act on them? According to Newton's law, some force must be acting on them right?

Comment: Neurons, Chemical Signals....

Comment: Now you need to go to a biology forum... and ask them why muscles contract?

Comment: @Godparticle, your question in the comment seems to be quite different to the main one. Please clarify what "exactly" is the question.

Comment: @varun: Thank you for the suggestion, I have made possible changes.

Comment: I have edited the question.